# Filling QML ListView with data from std::map

Tags: c++, qt, mvvm, qml

I'm having trouble finding a good way to display the items of a `std::map` in QML. We're using a MVVM pattern in our application. The `std::map` contains file paths and is a member of a configuration class in the model.
Now I'm trying to show all entries of the map in QML, probably using a `ListView` item.
Currently we just have a couple of file paths in the configuration, so these are exposed as `Q_PROPERTY`ies to the view model and then further to QML. But, of course, the number of paths can and will grow, thus my idea using a `std::map` for this. It won't be necessary to have it 'growable' at runtime, at least not in the forseeable future. But writing lots and lots of `Q_PROPERTY`ies doesn't seem the right way for me.

Furhter question: How would I access/display the items of the map in a QML `ListView` - I can't figure it out and I can't find anything helpful online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option than @ddriver suggested would be to create a list of QObject-derived types like:

```
class ConfigObject: public QObject
{
    Q_PROPERTY(QString key READ key)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString value READ value)
    // ... getters and key and value members
};
```

fill a QList with them and provide them as a model for ListView either via

```
QVariantList configModel;
// ... fill it with ConfigObjects from std::map
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("configModel", &configModel); //QQmlApplicationEngine here
```

or a property of some class:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariant configModel READ configModel NOTIFY configModelChanged)
```

Then you should be able to use it via `modelData.key` and modelData.value in your ListView delegate.

```
ListView {
    model: configModel // in case of using context
    delegate: Item {
        ...
        Text {
            text: modelData.key
        }
        Text {
            text: modelData.value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good, thank you for providing an alternate solution and exemplary code pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a model adapter for `std::map` by extending a `QAbstractListModel`, then you can use that as the model for a QML `ListView`. Implementing the right set of model roles will allow you to access the map element members without the need to use `Q_PROPERTY` which also requires a `QObject` derived datatype. Then you only need to expose the model to QML, as a context property for example.

Keep in mind the map is a sorted container, so if you modify the model you  should properly reflect the index of insertion and deletion.

So you will have:

`std::map -> YourCustomListModel -> ListView`

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, I found bits and pieces that indicated to this solution, but couldn't put them together, thanks! Chose @rightaway717 's answer since it also has some code.

Comment: You will eventually run into a situation that calls for creating your own model. I have posted an implementation of a generic QML object model here, the only difference is this one uses QList instead of std::map for storage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160909/how-to-create-a-generic-object-model-for-use-in-qml/35161903#35161903