# How to create a Generic ListModel for QML

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qml

My application consists of many Lists that I display in QML-ListViews by using QAbstractListModel derived model-classes. It's always the same, with the difference of the Item-Type. That's why I want to know how to build a class-template for this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out, that it is not possible to use the Q_OBJECT-Macro in a class-template. That's why my GenericListModel consists of two part.

**1. GenericListModelData**

The first part is the Model itself that derives from QAbstractListModel and implements the basic functions data(), rowCount() and roleNames().

**2. GenericListModel**

The second part is the class-template that is used as a wrapper to provide functions similar to a QListView.

If you have any suggestions or questions please let me know. It would be really nice to improve this solution.

I uploaded the full sourcecode here:
https://github.com/sebabebibobu/QGenericListModel/

**1. GenericListModelData**

```
QVariant GenericListModelData::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QObject *item = m_itemList.at(index.row());
    return item->property(item->metaObject()->property(role).name());
}

/*
 * Returns the number of items attached to the list.
 */
int GenericListModelData::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent)
    return m_itemList.size();
}

/*
 * Generates a hash out of QMetaObject property-index and property-name.
 */
QHash<int, QByteArray> GenericListModelData::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;

    if (!m_itemList.isEmpty()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_itemList.at(0)->metaObject()->propertyCount(); i++) {
            roles[i] = m_itemList.at(0)->metaObject()->property(i).name();
        }
    }

    return roles;
}

/*
 * Append Item to List.
 */
void GenericListModelData::appendItem(QObject *item)
{
    /* map the notify()-signal-index with the property-index when the first item get's inserted */
    if (m_itemList.isEmpty()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < item->metaObject()->propertyCount(); i++) {
            m_propertySignalIndexHash.insert(item->metaObject()->property(i).notifySignalIndex(), i);
        }
    }

    /* connect each notify()-signals to the onDataChanged()-slot which call's the dataChanged()-signal */
    for(int i = 0; i < item->metaObject()->propertyCount(); i++) {
        connect(item, "2" + item->metaObject()->property(i).notifySignal().methodSignature(), this, SLOT(onDataChanged()));
    }

    /* finally append the item the list */
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_itemList.append(item);
    endInsertRows();
}

/*
 * Helper-Slot that emit's the dataChanged()-signal of QAbstractListModel.
 */
void GenericListModelData::onDataChanged()
{
    QModelIndex index = createIndex(m_itemList.indexOf(sender()),0);

    QVector<int> roles;
    roles.append(m_propertySignalIndexHash.value(senderSignalIndex()));
    emit dataChanged(index, index, roles);
}
```

**2. GenericListModel**

```
template <typename T>
class GenericListModel : public GenericListModelData
{
public:
    explicit GenericListModel(QObject *parent) : GenericListModelData(parent) {

    }

    void append(T *item) {
        appendItem(item);
    }

    T *at(int i) {
        return qobject_cast<T *>(m_itemList.at(i));
    }
};
```

**Update 01.05.2016**

GrecKo posted in the comments, that a project like mine already exists. That's why I decided to share the link of this project here too:

http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-qml-tricks/qt-qml-models

Comment: Take a look at `QQmlObjectListModel` here : http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-qml-tricks/qt-qml-models/

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160909/how-to-create-a-generic-object-model-for-use-in-qml/35161903#35161903