# Collection of ListModel in QML

Tags: qt, collections, qml, listmodel

How can I create a Collection of `ListModel`
Each list `ListModel` conatains 5 `ListElement`

```
ListModel{
    ListElement {
        type:"1"
        title:"5:03pm"
        description:"text-1"
        isLoaded: false   
    }
    ListElement {
        type:"1"
        title:"5:03pm"
        description:"text-1"
        isLoaded: false   
    }
    ListElement {
        type:"1"
        title:"5:03pm"
        description:"text-1"
        isLoaded: false   
    }
    ListElement {
        type:"1"
        title:"5:03pm"
        description:"text-1"
        isLoaded: false   
    }
    ListElement {
        type:"1"
        title:"5:03pm"
        description:"text-1"
        isLoaded: false   
    }
}
```

One model is like this . I want to create a qml with 2 or 3 `ListModel` collection

How can I create the collection.

**Edit:**
 I want to create the Collection of models dynamically. 
Each list model contains maximum 5 elements. once it reaches count 5 then I need to create another ListModel with elements. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection would be represented by a property that is essentially a JS array. On inserting elements you check whether the collection doesn't contains a model, or if it does, whether the model already has 5 elements, if so you add another model to it, then append the item to the last model in the collection:

```
  id: main
  property var models: []
  Component {
    id: mod
    ListModel {}
  }
  function addItem(type, title, desc) {
    if (!models.length || models[models.length - 1].count > 4) models.push(mod.createObject(main))
    models[models.length - 1].append({"type": type, "title": title, "description": desc})
  }
```

Comment: Actually I need to create the Collection of models dynamically.

Comment: each list model contains maximum 5 elements. once it reaches count 5 then I want to create another ListModel with elements. And so on.

Comment: @VineeshTP - you should clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do this properly in C++, with one object providing a list of models or a model that has models as its content.

That avoids scripting/data handling on the QML side, allowing explicit control of the state, even reload QML, etc.
Also does not have any of the limitations of `ListModel`, e.g. allows for translated text.

Comment: Or use the "generic object model" and have model items be objects with arbitrary properties, signals and whatnot... all customizable on the qml side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160909/how-to-create-a-generic-object-model-for-use-in-qml/35161903#35161903