# QML ListModel onDataChanged issues

Tags: javascript, qt, callback, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I'm trying to implement a callback function on my QML ListModel to do some operations when the data inside the ListModel changes. Apparently, it's impossible to create on...Changed handlers for individual user-defined properties in a ListModel. So, I'm trying to use the onDataChanged handler available to ListModel.

```
ListModel {
    id: model

    onDataChanged: {
        console.warn("onDataChanged: "+get(topLeft).val + " vs. " + get(bottomRight).val)
    }
}
```

However, onDataChanged only ever seems to reference the very first element in the ListModel. That is to say, topLeft and bottomRight always point to the first element, even when I manipulate an element down the list.

What I need here is a reliable handler that accurately reflects the correct row in the ListModel when it fires off.

Comment: If you use a [generic object model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160909/how-to-create-a-generic-object-model-for-use-in-qml/35161903#35161903) you can then use regular properties with individual change notifications.

Comment: Not possible due to constraints of project. Why would onDataChanged return the very first row when I manipulate a different row? Am I just using these parameters incorrectly?

Comment: The arguments of `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged()` are `QModelIndex`, i.e. objects of a class type.

You are passing these to functions expecting integers, the JavaScript environment will likely do one of its magic type conversions.

Using a ListModel for data that changes is odd, usually indicates that a proper custom model would be better.

Answer (score 0):

When I change the data in a `ListModel` everything seems right.
Try this example:

```
Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1200
    height: 800

    ListModel {
        id: lm
        ListElement { test: 0 }
        ListElement { test: 0 }
        ListElement { test: 0 }
        ListElement { test: 0 }
        ListElement { test: 0 }

        onDataChanged: console.log('Data Changed', topLeft.row, get(topLeft.row).test, data(topLeft, roles[0]))
    }

    ListView {
        width: 200
        height: 800
        model: lm
        delegate: Button {
            text: model.test
            onClicked: model.test++
        }
    }
}
```

The QML-`get`-function expects a Integer that indicates the index, which corresponds to the `QModelIndex.row`. Mark that in QML you have the row as property, so `.row()` will fail.

What you can alternatively use is the `data(index, role)`-method. This takes a `QModelIndex` as index, and the `role` as Integer. This is fortunate, as I know no *non-hacky* way to retrive the mapping from the integer-typed roles provided by the signal, into the `roleName`s usually used in QML.