# QML - Accessing QObject class properties which is stored in QList

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qproperty

I am having trouble in accessing a property in **QML**.

**QList** is a property and i am able to access that but when i try to access the properties of **classB** in QML i am getting type error/Undefined. Following is the code:

**[EDIT 1]** - Changed the QList to QVariantList Based on the suggestion:

**//ClassA.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include "classb.h"

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<ClassB*>)
class ClassA : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList objList READ getClassBDetails) //[EDIT 1]

public:
    explicit ClassA(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVariantList getClassBDetails(); //[EDIT 1]

private:
    QVariantList  m_list; //[EDIT 1]
    ClassB m_Bobj;

};
```

**//ClassA.cpp**

```
#include "classa.h"

ClassA::ClassA(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_list.append(QVariant::fromValue(&m_Bobj)); //** Appending to QvariantList
}

QVariantList  ClassA ::getClassBDetails() //[EDIT 1]
{
    return m_list;
}
```

**//ClassB.h**

```
#include <QObject>

class ClassB : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int val READ getval WRITE setval NOTIFY valChanged)
public:
    explicit ClassB(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int m_val = 10;

    int getval();
    void setval(int val);

signals:
    void valChanged();

public slots:
};
```

**//ClassB.cpp**

```
#include "classb.h"
ClassB::ClassB(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

int ClassB::getval()
{
    return m_val;
}

void ClassB::setval(int val)
{
    m_val = val;
    emit valChanged();
}
```

**//Main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "classa.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    ClassA aObj;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("classAObj",&aObj);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**//Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("value========",classAObj.objList[0].val) //** Same error  
    }
}
```

If i try to access `"classAObj.objList[0].val"` i am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined` error. What is that i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is expecting the `[]` operator to work. It won't.

There is one way to get it to work, if you convert your `QList` to a `QVariantList` which QML will automatically convert to a JS array.

But what I actually recommend is to simply use accessory functions instead, implement a `get(index)` and if necessary a `set(index)` function and you are set.

You can also take a look at this [generic object list model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160909/how-to-create-a-generic-object-model-for-use-in-qml/35161903#35161903), which is very flexible, powerful and useful, supports any `QObject` children, including objects that are defined in QML, declarative and nested definitions and last but not least, it can be directly used as a model.

Comment: I actually tried with **QVariantList**, But I was not able to insert `ClassB` object to it .Can you please give an example?

Comment: I am not sure how "editable" such implicitly converted lists are. I suggest you don't bother with that. If you want to insert from C++, you will obviously be inserting a `QVariant::fromValue(objPtr)`, and since it is just a `QList<QVariant>` you insert the same way you insert in any `QList`.

Comment: Thanks and i am able to pass now . After that can I access using `[ ]` operator ?? Because I did like this `var res = classAObj.objDetails` and later I tried to print it something like this `res[0]` ... And getting same error ..

Comment: Did you change to `QVariantList`? It should work. It is possible that you may need to return from a `Q_INVOKABLE` function rather than use a property. As I already recommended - don't bother with that. Not exactly sure why you insist to make your live harder.

Comment: Yes i changed in `Q_PROPERTY` declaration and also return type of function  `getClassBDetails` to QVariantList, it didn't work. I also changed `getClassBDetails` to `Q_INVOKABLE` and called directly from QML even that didn't work. I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting. it's a serious problem for me. @dtech I tried all possible ways. please help.

Comment: I have already given you a better way. I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: I have edited the question by updated the code to use `QVariantList`. Can you please check? I am stuck here.