# change c++ QAbstractListModel values from Qml

Tags: qt, qml

this is my code

devicemodel.h

```
class Device
{
public:
    Device(const int &nodeId ,const QString &type, const int &lampVoltage);
//![0]

    QString type() const;
    int lampVoltage() const;
    int nodeId() const;
public:
    QString m_type;
    int m_lampVoltage;
    int m_nodeId;
//![1]


};

class DeviceModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum DeviceRoles {
        NodeIdRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        TypeRole ,
        LampVoltageRole

    };

    DeviceModel(QObject *parent = 0);
//![1]

    void addDevice(const Device &Device);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QList<Device> m_Devices;
//![2]

public slots :
    void callFromQml(int index);

};
```

devicemodel.cpp

```
Device::Device(const int &nodeId ,const QString &type, const int &lampVoltage)
    : m_nodeId(nodeId) , m_type(type), m_lampVoltage(lampVoltage)
{
}

QString Device::type() const
{
    return m_type;
}

int Device::nodeId() const
{
    return m_nodeId;
}

int Device::lampVoltage() const
{
    return m_lampVoltage;
}

DeviceModel::DeviceModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}



void DeviceModel::callFromQml(int index){

   Device k= m_Devices.at(index);
   qDebug() << k.type() << k.lampVoltage();
   k.m_lampVoltage = 5;
    emit dataChanged(createIndex(index,0), createIndex(index,0), {0,1,2} );
}

void DeviceModel::addDevice(const Device &Device)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_Devices << Device;
    endInsertRows();
}

int DeviceModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_Devices.count();
}

QVariant DeviceModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_Devices.count())
        return QVariant();

    const Device &Device = m_Devices[index.row()];
    if (role == NodeIdRole)
        return Device.nodeId();
    else if (role == TypeRole)
        return Device.type();
    else if (role == LampVoltageRole)
        return Device.lampVoltage();
    return QVariant();
}

//![0]
QHash<int, QByteArray> DeviceModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[NodeIdRole] = "nodeId";
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[LampVoltageRole] = "lampVoltage";
    return roles;
}
```

main.qml

```
ListView {
    width: 200; height: 250
    spacing: 10
    model: myModel
    delegate:
        Text { text: "Animal: " + type + ", " + lampVoltage

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log("egwegweg");
                myModel.callFromQml(index);
                //lampVoltage = 10;

               // myModel.setData(index , 10 , 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    DeviceModel model;
    model.addDevice(Device(1, "Medium" , 200));
    model.addDevice(Device(1, "Medium" , 200));
    model.addDevice(Device(1, "Medium" , 200));
    QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    model.addDevice(Device(1, "Medium" , 200));
    model.addDevice(Device(1, "Medium" , 200));
    model.addDevice(Device(1, "Medium" , 200));

    return app.exec();
```

i want modify my item values from Qml
i wrote a slot named `callFromQml` and pass index of item from qml to c++ code and want update the values from it
but can not do it 
i don not know emit signal works or not and do not know pass index to it correctly or not and don not

Comment: Not really an answer, but something that will save you a lot of time and effort: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161903/991484

Comment: You can just add a `Q_INVOKABLE` that takes a integer index, a rolename and a value. Internally the method will translate the integer index into a `ModelIndex` and calls [`setData(...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) with this. Alternatively, I think, if you write to `model.someRole = someNewValue` it will be automatically written back through some magic.

Comment: i can not understand how do it properly can you provide me snippet code?

Comment: @derM there will be no automagically writing back, unless the setData() method of the model is implemented surely?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have not realized that `setData()` was not implemented, though in the doucmentation it is stated, this is a requirement for editable models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for *@MarkCh* for pointing out, that you have not reimplemented the [`setData()`-method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData).

The signature is:

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)
```

It returns `true` if some data was set successfully, and `false` if not.
Further, uppon success, before returning, it is necessary to `emit dataChanged(...)` so any views will be aware of the change.

Let's do it:

1. Add the appropriate declaration to the header file
2. Add the implementation to the `.cpp`-file. This might look like this:

---

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_Devices.count())
        return false;

    const Device &Device = m_Devices[index.row()];
    if (role == NodeIdRole) {
        Device.m_nodeId = value.toInt();
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }
    else if (role == TypeRole) {
        Device.m_type = value.toString();
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }
    else if (role == LampVoltageRole) {
        Device.m_lampVoltage = value.toInt();
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

3. Make `DeviceModel` a `friend` of `Device` or change the access of the private fields to usage of getters. As you like.

---

Now you should be able to set the roles in the delegate as if they were properties... Like:

```
onClicked: model.nodeId = 100;
```

> The code above is not tested, but should include the most relevant details.