# How do I find and use QML child elements in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt4, qt5

I am trying to make a QML Object that I can add an arbitrary number of children to and then manipulate them in C++. I have code that works, but I think that I have the wrong approach, especially since it involves a text search.

```
void Foo::componentComplete()
{
    QObjectList children = this->children();

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length(); i++)
    {
        if(QString(children[i]->metaObject()->className()).contains("MyClass"))
        {
            this->myChildList.append(static_cast<MyClass*>(children[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

One example of this can be found in the [QML charts example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmlchart-example.html).

Here is one excerpt from the code. Even though the PiceSlice child elements are not assigned to properties of the PieSeries element, they are discovered and displayed by the chart. How does this work under the hood? Is it just using `this->children()` or is there a better method?

```
ChartView {
    id: chart
    title: "Top-5 car brand shares in Finland"
    anchors.fill: parent
    legend.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
    antialiasing: true

    PieSeries {
        id: pieSeries
        PieSlice { label: "Volkswagen"; value: 13.5 }
        PieSlice { label: "Toyota"; value: 10.9 }
        PieSlice { label: "Ford"; value: 8.6 }
        PieSlice { label: "Skoda"; value: 8.2 }
        PieSlice { label: "Volvo"; value: 6.8 }
    }
}
```

---

Here is the complete source at Github

[Source](https://github.com/kyle7119/47818560)

Comment: Where is Foo in the qml?

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]

Comment: Take a look at my universal object model class here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160909/how-to-create-a-generic-object-model-for-use-in-qml - it can be populated declaratively in QML or imperatively from C++ or QML, it is directly usable as a model, it is type agnostic and can be nested to create trees.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added the complete source code

Comment: What does your code have to do with PieSeries and PieSlice?

Comment: I see that it works correctly, why do you say it does not work?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the path I always use is for QML to read from a C++ model's `Q_PROPERTY` to get some sort of QJSonObject or QJsonArray that the QML iterates over using nested [`Repeater`'s](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) .